# Ember required component arguments

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I require a parameter in an ember component.

E.g.:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  get my_value() {
    return this.args.my_argument + 1
  }
}
```

I want the component to throw an error when the component is instantiated and not when the function is called.

The only way I can think of is like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(owner, args) {
    super(owner, args)
    assert(!!args.my_argument, "MyComponent requires my_argument")
  }
  ...
}
```

This however seems a bit tedious and does not look right :/

EDIT:

It would be even better if I could specify the type of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you are on the right track with your assert. If you want to make sure that it is of the right type as well you can always assert with a typeof.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(owner, args) {
    super(owner, args)
    assert("MyComponent requires my_argument", typeof args.my_argument === "string")
  }
  ...
}
```

What to remember however is that asserts are only available during development builds, it is removed from any production builds. So if you need this check in your production build you'll have to write your own assertion method.

> Assertions are removed from production builds, so they can be freely added for documentation and debugging purposes without worries of incuring any performance penalty. However, because of that, they should not be used for checks that could reasonably fail during normal usage.

https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fdebug/assert

Comment: I already thought that there is no satisfying solution for this. Maybe I should introduce typescript to solve these unnecessary bugs. Sure it makes sense to have the assertions only in the development code :)